# Android-Best way to check how old lastKnownLocation is

Tags: android, google-maps, location

In an app Im working on Im using a backoff pattern of different location listeners and this works just fine but in the case that the location isnt available Im allowing the app to default to the lastknownlocation and sometimes the app will only use this and not update its location. How can I check the time when the lastKnownLocation was updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply call [getTime()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#getTime%28%29) on whatever location you get, for instance on the location you get from [`LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29). Then calculating the *age* of that data is trivial.

Comment: Your solution sounds a lot easier since I dont have to save a position and time I can just make sure if the lastKnownLocation is older than so many minutes :) thanks

Comment: Yeah, plus: It also works if the last fix happened before your App even started.

Answer (score 1):

In LocationListener, **onLocationChanged()** will be called when location updated from the given Location Provider, you know this. So in this method only, take current time and save it. You can **compare this in your app with current time** to know whether the last known location is currently updated or not.

To get current date and time use below code

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

If you want only time without date, you can extract from string.

Comment: Hey thanks for that :) I wasnt sure if the locationmanager or locationlistener had some method to do what I wanted but Ill try this out and post back :)

Comment: @Jamesandresakis [Check this link to know how to use LocationListener](http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/)

Comment: @Yugandhar Babu: To get the parts of a `Date` you would just use a `Calendar`. - Absolutely no need to build a string and extract anything from it.